# Por que uma função aceita uma referência ao invés de retornar um valor?

Tags: c, funções, referência

Consideremos o trecho de código abaixo:

```
int num;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Eu entendo que, ao passar `&num` ao segundo argumento de `scanf()`, passo a referência da variável `num`, que será modificada pela implementação de `scanf()`.

No entanto, fico na dúvida por trás da motivação desse tipo de API. Não seria mais propenso a erros (passar por exemplo, uma referência perdida ou que já foi liberada)? Porque não simplesmente *retornar* o valor digitado de `scanf()`?

Com certeza deve haver uma motivação para essa escolha. Qual é? Tem a ver com a (provável) impossibilidade de se inferir o tipo de retorno?

Comment: *Porque não simplesmente retornar o valor digitado de scanf?* - porque vc pode ler vários valores de uma vez: `scanf("%d %s %f", &inteiro, arraydechar, &floatingpoint)` - e o retorno é a quantidade de itens que foram lidos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Motivos gerais:

- é mais interessante alterar um local de armazenamento existente do que criar um novo, o retorno tradicional realiza uma cópia
- você precisa retornar mais de um valor, o que é complicado, não econômico em alguns sentidos, então "retornar" através de uma referência é a solução.

Pode querer retornar uma quantidade de valores diversos, este é um dos motivos que o `scanf()` permite isso, mas também pode ser dois valores e forma específica, ou seja, o valor em si que deseja, e uma informação se deu certo ou não, ou como deu certo.

Passar uma referência é mais comum do que parece, em muitas linguagens isso acontece muito sem a pessoa ver que é uma referência (em orientação a objeto é sempre assim). Então a API não é tão fora do normal quanto as pessoas podem pensar. Em C sempre foi mais bruto, ele mostra para você.

Se fosse filosofia de C poderia passar um objeto e ter todas informações diretamente nele, seria uma passagem por referência, talvez implicitamente e você não estaria "reclamando" :) Mas C gosta de ser explícito, então precisa ter como informar ao consumidor quantos itens foram lidos de forma correta (pode ser 0), e entregar todos os valores que o consumidor disse que poderia receber.

Nada a ver com inferência do tipo de retorno, inclusive porque isso não ocorre. Na verdade especificamente com o `scanf()` tem a complicação que as variáveis podem ser de tipos diferentes. Se o compilador não é bom, seria igual linguagens de tipagem dinâmica. É que hoje os compiladores leem a *string* de formatação e tentam barrar algum erro, mas é um comportamento especial. Você tem que definir o tipo de todas variáveis de qualquer forma, não é como algumas pessoas pensam que depende do que digita o tipo da variável muda.

Se você quisesse fazer uma função que só lê um dado e é garantido que vai funcionar e não precisa informar mais nada, ou considerar que um nulo já pode informar que deu problema, então poderia fazer retornar um valor. Mas teria um outro problema, deveria ter um `scanf_int()`, um `scanf_str()`, um `scanf_double()`, etc.

A motivação é mais geral, mas o `scanf()` tem motivação mais específica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).